# HTML Search suggestion with Ajax doesn't auto complete with keyboard

Tags: php, html, css, ajax

I am developing a web application in PHP with a MySql database, and made a search suggestion box with ajax.
The problem is that I can select the suggestions with my mouse and it auto completes but when I try to auto complete it with my keyboard (select it with arrow up arrow down and pressing enter) it does nothing.
Is this a problem of my css, ajax or just html??? Could you please help with this, All help is appreciated, Thanks.

Here is my code :
Ajax

```
$term = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['term']); if(isset($term)){

// Attempt select query execution

$sql = "SELECT * FROM something WHERE name LIKE '" . $term . "%' LIMIT 4";

if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

            echo "<p>" . $row['name'] . "</p>";

        }

        // Close result set

        mysqli_free_result($result);

    } else{

        echo "<p>No Results</p>";

    }

} else{

    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);

} }
```

CSS

```
   .result{  position: absolute;        

    z-index: 999;

    top: 100%;

    left: 0;

}

.search-box input[type="text"], .result{

    width: 100%;

    box-sizing: border-box;

}

/* Formatting result items */

.result p{

    margin: 0;

    padding: 7px 10px;

    border: 0px solid #CCCCCC;

    border-top: none;

    cursor: pointer;

    background: #ffffff;

}

.result p:hover{

    background: #f2f2f2;

}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){

    /* Get input value on change */

    var inputVal = $(this).val();

    var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");

    if(inputVal.length){

        $.get("something.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){

            // Display the returned data in browser

            resultDropdown.html(data);

        });

    } else{

        resultDropdown.empty();

    }

});



// Set search input value on click of result item

$(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){

    $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());

    $(this).parent(".result").empty();

}); });
```

HTML

```
<form align=center method='POST' action='index.php?cmd=list-something'>
            <h1 class="text-center">Search</h1>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group search-box">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search"/>
                        <div class="result"></div>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"><span style="margin-left:10px;">Pesquisar</span></button>
                    </span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer this [Autocomplete library docs](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp).

You can implement normal AJAX for fetching records and render those records using Autocomplete library.

Comment: I tried just now, and it didn't change nothing, could it be the fact of in the ajax I am returning `<p>` and it should be `<ul><li>`?

Comment: yes, possible you just need to give response as data only without any tags, library will build tags automatically. you can check console for response and get idea which type of data its returning.

Comment: its not working any ways... and if I return only data, it's even worse, I think its the div css properties problem

Comment: Okay, Please make jsfiddle so I can check it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/web1mjys/ here it is but its not exactly like that and its really messy (first time using it) but it gets the picture, u can only hoover the lines with keyboard nothing

Comment: it seems not working, I'm typing in textbox but not populating results.

Comment: u have to go to the bottom of the result and theres some values , I dont know why they went to the bottom